# Get XML value using ElementTree in Python When they have the same name

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML file :

```
<Device Name="VPV I 6000/1 400V" Type="Inverter" Platform="Net13" HmiPlatform="HMI17" NominalPower="6000" UserPowerLimit="nan" CountryPowerLimit="nan" Serial="763427EF006828565017" OEMSerial="21192300100247250942005017N2" BusAddress="1" NetBiosName="INV006828565017" WebPortal="Vaillant" ManufacturerURL="" IpAddress="http://81.241.188.178:43380/" DateTime="2021-04-24T19:10:55" MilliSeconds="699">
<Measurements>
<Measurement Value="232.9" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage1"/>
<Measurement Value="233.2" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage2"/>
<Measurement Value="232.4" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage3"/>
<Measurement Value="0.244" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current1"/>
<Measurement Value="0.244" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current2"/>
<Measurement Value="0.245" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current3"/>
<Measurement Value="122.9" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power"/>
<Measurement Value="126.7" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power_fast"/>
<Measurement Value="42.8" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power1"/>
<Measurement Value="41.5" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power2"/>
<Measurement Value="42.4" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power3"/>
<Measurement Value="50.038" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency1"/>
<Measurement Value="50.033" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency2"/>
<Measurement Value="50.036" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency3"/>
<Measurement Value="601.3" Unit="V" Type="DC_Voltage"/>
<Measurement Value="0.204" Unit="A" Type="DC_Current"/>
<Measurement Value="601.5" Unit="V" Type="LINK_Voltage"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridConsumedPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridInjectedPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="OwnConsumedPower"/>
<Measurement Value="100.0" Unit="%" Type="Derating"/>
</Measurements>
</Device>
</root>
```

And what Im triyng is to get the value of AC-Power
Like that : 122.9
But the problem is that all the elements have the exact same name

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is good for xml parsing.
algo:

1. create a beautiful soup, with XML parser
2. find all the elements and store them in list
3. loop through the elements, and find attribute parameters and their value. example each['Type']

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml="""
<Measurements>
<Measurement Value="232.9" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage1"/>
<Measurement Value="233.2" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage2"/>
<Measurement Value="232.4" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage3"/>
<Measurement Value="0.244" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current1"/>
<Measurement Value="0.244" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current2"/>
<Measurement Value="0.245" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current3"/>
<Measurement Value="122.9" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power"/>
<Measurement Value="126.7" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power_fast"/>
<Measurement Value="42.8" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power1"/>
<Measurement Value="41.5" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power2"/>
<Measurement Value="42.4" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power3"/>
<Measurement Value="50.038" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency1"/>
<Measurement Value="50.033" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency2"/>
<Measurement Value="50.036" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency3"/>
<Measurement Value="601.3" Unit="V" Type="DC_Voltage"/>
<Measurement Value="0.204" Unit="A" Type="DC_Current"/>
<Measurement Value="601.5" Unit="V" Type="LINK_Voltage"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridConsumedPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridInjectedPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="OwnConsumedPower"/>
<Measurement Value="100.0" Unit="%" Type="Derating"/>
</Measurements>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,"xml")
all_elements=(soup.find_all('Measurement'))
for each in all_elements:
    try:
        print(f"{each['Type']} : {each['Value']}")
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

See below (Use ElementTree & XPATH)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root><Device Name="VPV I 6000/1 400V" Type="Inverter" Platform="Net13" HmiPlatform="HMI17" NominalPower="6000" UserPowerLimit="nan" CountryPowerLimit="nan" Serial="763427EF006828565017" OEMSerial="21192300100247250942005017N2" BusAddress="1" NetBiosName="INV006828565017" WebPortal="Vaillant" ManufacturerURL="" IpAddress="http://81.241.188.178:43380/" DateTime="2021-04-24T19:10:55" MilliSeconds="699">
<Measurements>
<Measurement Value="232.9" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage1"/>
<Measurement Value="233.2" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage2"/>
<Measurement Value="232.4" Unit="V" Type="AC_Voltage3"/>
<Measurement Value="0.244" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current1"/>
<Measurement Value="0.244" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current2"/>
<Measurement Value="0.245" Unit="A" Type="AC_Current3"/>
<Measurement Value="122.9" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power"/>
<Measurement Value="126.7" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power_fast"/>
<Measurement Value="42.8" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power1"/>
<Measurement Value="41.5" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power2"/>
<Measurement Value="42.4" Unit="W" Type="AC_Power3"/>
<Measurement Value="50.038" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency1"/>
<Measurement Value="50.033" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency2"/>
<Measurement Value="50.036" Unit="Hz" Type="AC_Frequency3"/>
<Measurement Value="601.3" Unit="V" Type="DC_Voltage"/>
<Measurement Value="0.204" Unit="A" Type="DC_Current"/>
<Measurement Value="601.5" Unit="V" Type="LINK_Voltage"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridConsumedPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="GridInjectedPower"/>
<Measurement Unit="W" Type="OwnConsumedPower"/>
<Measurement Value="100.0" Unit="%" Type="Derating"/>
</Measurements>
</Device>
</root>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for ac_power in root.findall(".//Measurement[@Type='AC_Power']"):
    print(ac_power.attrib['Value'])
```

output

```
122.9
```